# update value inside array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I only want to replace the `name` with the new name being typed in from the user. I'm using react redux typescript and its proving to be quite difficult. All the passed in arguments work, the `newName` and `index`, I just need to update the array object then return it with only the name in the index object changed.

My code:

Action:

```
export const updateName = (newName: string, index: number) => (
  dispatch: (arg0: { type?: string; newName: string; index: number }) => any
) => {
  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_NAME,
    newName,
    index
  });
};
```

Reducer:

```
case UPDATE_NAME:
      return {
        ...state
        items[action.index].name: action.newName,

      };
```

State looks like this:

```
items: Array(50)
0: {id: "1d0b1095-f0b4-4881-8d5e-74c86d5beee2", name: "A Ipsum Debitis", participants: {…},
1: {id: "7384a574-1592-484e-9404-e876bf45410c", name: "Distinctio Blanditiis Voluptatibus Ut", participants: {…},
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with shallow copying the state object, you need to shallow copy any nested state that is being updated as well, i.e. `state.items` and the specific array element that is being updated.

```
case UPDATE_NAME:
  return {
    ...state,
    items: state.items.map((el, i) => i === action.index ? {
      ...el,
      name: action.newName,
    } : el),
  };
```

Comment: I get this message "(parameter) el: never
Spread types may only be created from object types.ts(2698)"

Comment: @artworkjpm Yup, exactly, you need to type the map callback function. Seems `el` would have a type similar to `{ id: string, name: string, participants: any }`.